# Inspect element in IE finding different DOM elements than other browers?

Tags: html, wordpress, internet-explorer

So while trying to help a friend with there wordpress website I noticed something very strange in regards to the "inspect element" tool in IE vs other browers. When I inspect the title of his blog post with IE's inspect element tool it proceeds to say that the element I'm inspecting is an h1 tag. But when I inspect that same element in other web browsers like firefox and chrome, their inspect element tools say its an h2 tag. What the heck is going on? Is it something wrong with IE? I don't understand how two different browsers come up with two differents answers for HTML elements. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Without code or links, we can't troubleshoot the site directly; that makes it hard to guess why there might be differences. It's possible that browsers represent the DOM differently; however, they'll all fairly aligned to various specs that are (mostly) specific about how things are parsed and rendered, at least with respect to basic HTML elements. More likely, your friend is using markup that sends different markup to IE than it sends to other browsers, perhaps presuming (incorrectly) that IE11 has the same capabilities as IE6/IE8/whatever. Look for (and remove) CSS hacks or browser sniffing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each browser use different rendering engines so expect that each browser will render pages differently.

IE uses an engine called Trident: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(layout_engine)

Safari use Webkit:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit

Google's Chrome now use Blink: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(layout_engine)

Firefox uses the Gecko: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(software)

Comment: Okay maybe it has something to do with that then. It's really the only explanation there is

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could come up with is that it may be conditional based on which browser you're viewing the page from, and that IE is not the best anyway.